# CSS Different grids for desktop and mobile version

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

I have a grid layout, which has 7 columns and 5 rows, defined by following CSS:

```
.container {

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;

}
```

[image]

I have to rearrange its cells for mobile version and if I have same numbers of cells, it could be done without any JavaScript coding just we a simple CSS trick (see attached code snippet), where I have redesigned layout for mobile devices and put LF/RF cells down.

But, what if I couldn't keep the same number of cells?

What if, desktop grid would have additional 4 offset cells (magenta ones)

[image]

So, is it possible to switch between desktop and mobile layouts if they don't have even number of cells, but same # of grids and rows.
Without using JavaScript, just HTML/CSS stack.

```css
     
    body {margin: 0; }
    .container {
        
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
        grid-column-gap: 0px;
        grid-row-gap: 0px;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        
    }

    /*desktop*/
    .l1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3; background-color: aqua; }
    .c1 { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 6; background-color: aquamarine; }
    .r1 { grid-area: 1 / 6 / 2 / 8; background-color: aqua; }
    .ltotal { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 4; background-color:burlywood; }
    .c2{ grid-area: 2 / 4 / 3 / 5; background-color: darkgray; }
    .rtotal { grid-area: 2 / 5 / 3 / 8; background-color:burlywood; }
    .lf { grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2; background-color: brown; }
    .d3 { grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 7; background-color: cadetblue; }
    .rf { grid-area: 3 / 7 / 4 / 8; background-color: blueviolet; }
    .lui { grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 4; background-color: aqua; }
    .cui { grid-area: 4 / 4 / 5 / 5; background-color: aquamarine; }
    .rui { grid-area: 4 / 5 / 5 / 8; background-color: aqua; }
    .pholder { grid-area: 5 / 1 / 6 / 8; background-color: darkgray; }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

        .l1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3; }
        .c1 { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 6; }
        .r1 { grid-area: 1 / 6 / 2 / 8; }
        .ltotal { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 4; }
        .c2 { grid-area: 2 / 4 / 3 / 5; }
        .rtotal { grid-area: 2 / 5 / 3 / 8; }
        .d3 { grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 8; }
        .lui { grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 4; }
        .cui { grid-area: 4 / 4 / 5 / 5; }
        .rui { grid-area: 4 / 5 / 5 / 8; }
        .lf { grid-area: 5 / 1 / 6 / 4; }
        .pholder { grid-area: 5 / 4 / 6 / 5; }
        .rf { grid-area: 5 / 5 / 6 / 8; }
        
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Desktop vs. Mobile Grid</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="l1">L1</div>
    <div class="c1">C1</div>
    <div class="r1">R1</div>
    <div class="ltotal">LTOTAL</div>
    <div class="c2">C2</div>
    <div class="rtotal">RTOTAL</div>
    <div class="lf">LF</div>
    <div class="d3">D3</div>
    <div class="rf">RF</div>
    <div class="lui">LUI</div>
    <div class="cui">CUI</div>
    <div class="rui">RUI</div>
    <div class="pholder">PHOLDER</div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Once the DOM has loaded these styles, i mean you have loaded it in your browser, you can only manipulate your css styles using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I have to hide extra desktop cells by

```
display: none;
```

```css
    
    body {margin: 0; }
    .container {
        
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
        grid-column-gap: 0px;
        grid-row-gap: 0px;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        
    }

    /*desktop*/  
    .l1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3; background-color: aqua; }
    .c1 { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 6; background-color: aquamarine; }
    .r1 { grid-area: 1 / 6 / 2 / 8; background-color: aqua; }
    .desk1 { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; background-color: orange; }
    .ltotal { grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 4; background-color:burlywood; }
    .c2 { grid-area: 2 / 4 / 3 / 5; background-color: darkgray; }
    .rtotal { grid-area: 2 / 5 / 3 / 7; background-color:burlywood; }
    .desk2 { grid-area: 2 / 7 / 3 / 8; background-color: orange; }
    .lf { grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;  background-color: brown; }
    .d3 { grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 7; background-color: cadetblue; }
    .rf { grid-area: 3 / 7 / 4 / 8; background-color: blueviolet;}
    .desk3 { grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 2; background-color: orange; }
    .lui { grid-area: 4 / 2 / 5 / 4; background-color: aqua; }
    .cui { grid-area: 4 / 4 / 5 / 5; background-color: aquamarine; }
    .rui { grid-area: 4 / 5 / 5 / 7; background-color: aqua; }
    .desk4 { grid-area: 4 / 7 / 5 / 8; background-color: orange; }
    .pholder { grid-area: 5 / 1 / 6 / 8; background-color: darkgrey; }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

        .l1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3; }
        .c1 { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 6; }
        .r1 { grid-area: 1 / 6 / 2 / 8; }
        .ltotal { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 4; }
        .c2 { grid-area: 2 / 4 / 3 / 5; }
        .rtotal { grid-area: 2 / 5 / 3 / 8; }
        .d3 { grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 8; }
        .lui { grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 4; }
        .cui { grid-area: 4 / 4 / 5 / 5; }
        .rui { grid-area: 4 / 5 / 5 / 8; }
        .lf { grid-area: 5 / 1 / 6 / 4; }
        .pholder { grid-area: 5 / 4 / 6 / 5; }
        .rf { grid-area: 5 / 5 / 6 / 8; }
        .desk1 { display: none; }
        .desk2 { display: none; }
        .desk3 { display: none; }
        .desk4 { display: none; }
        
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Desktop vs. Mobile Grid</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="l1">L1</div>
    <div class="c1">C1</div>
    <div class="r1">R1</div>
    <div class="desk1"></div>
    <div class="ltotal">LTOTAL</div>
    <div class="c2">C2</div>
    <div class="rtotal">RTOTAL</div>
    <div class="desk2"></div>
    <div class="lf">LF</div>
    <div class="d3">D3</div>
    <div class="rf">RF</div>
    <div class="desk3"></div>
    <div class="lui">LUI</div>
    <div class="cui">CUI</div>
    <div class="rui">RUI</div>
    <div class="desk4"></div>
    <div class="pholder">PHOLDER</div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html
```